# How to populate a box as clicking on map with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Hi I'm trying some stuff on Google Maps API JavaScript and I've this problem with populating a text box.
I have a map and a geocoding box . I can directly input coordinates to this box and it makes reverse geocoding to the point. I also want to do this with right click . I want the box to be filled as I right click on the map. But couldn't do it.

- ### Here is the code I use ;

  ```
  <div id="floating-panel">
  <input id="latlng" type="text" value="40.714224,-73.961452">
  <input id="submit" type="button" value="Reverse Geocode">
  </div>
  <div id="map"></div>
  <script>
   function initMap() {
   var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 8,
    center: {lat: 40.731, lng: -73.997}
    });
    google.maps.event.addListener(map, "rightclick", function(event) {
    var lat = event.latLng.lat();
    var lng = event.latLng.lng();
    // populate yor box/field with lat, lng
    alert("Enlem=" + lat + "; Boylam=" + lng);
    floating-panel="latlng" type="text" value=lat+","+lng
  ```

  [image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hopefully this helps. The listener looked fine but they way you populate the input box is a bit unclear

"floating-panel="latlng" type="text" value=lat+","+lng"

```
       google.maps.event.addListener(map, "rightclick", function(event) {
            var lat = event.latLng.lat();
            var lng = event.latLng.lng();

            document.getElementById("latlng").value = lat.toFixed(5)+', '+lng.toFixed(5);

        });
```